# Sqlalchemy Core join two tables with no direct relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SqlAlchemy version 1.3.

There are three tables, I need to run a query that returns data from two of them (messages, accounts)

**models.py**

```
accounts = Table(
    "accounts",
    metadata,
    Column("user_id", ForeignKey(users.c.id), primary_key=True, ),
    Column("name", String(16), nullable=True),
    Column("surname", String(16), nullable=True),
    ...
)

users = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    ...
)

messages = Table(
    "messages",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("content", Text(), nullable=False),
    Column("sender", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("event", ForeignKey(events.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("recipient", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("created_at", DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=sql.func.now()),
)
```

I need to get data in the following form

```
[
(messages.sender, messages.event, messages.content, messages.created_at, accounts.name, account.surname),
....
]
```

I.e. four field values from messages and two from account. These tables are not directly related to each other, but have a common user value.

My query

```
user_message = messages.join(accounts, messages.c.sender == accounts.c.user_id)
query = select(
    [messages.c.sender, messages.c.event, messages.c.content, messages.c.created_at, accounts.name, accounts.surname]
).select_from(user_message).where(messages.c.recipient == user_id)
```

But this got an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual column expression 'accounts' should be explicitly declared with text('accounts'), or use column('accounts') for more specificity
```

How to correctly execute a query ?

Comment: You need to do accounts.c.[COLUMN_NAME] instead of accounts.[COLUMN_NAME]?

Comment: Yes, I was inattentive. That's exactly the point, thank you !